# Tail file that does not start with symbol

Tags: python-3.x, bash, csv, jupyter-notebook, text-processing

I have set of raw csv files that have comment headers (`#` symbol) in addition to column names. Like this:

```
# This data is taken from ....
# ...
# ...
# ...
# col1,col2,...,coln
#
[csv data rows starts here]
```

The number of lines above the row containing the column names is not fixed per file.

How to 'cut' the file (create a new file) that will output a standard CSV format?

```
col1,col2,...,coln
[csv data rows starts here]
```

I am using Jupyter notebook to do some data wrangling, so I am interested in doing this both using the inline shell script (using `tail` perhaps) and Python.

Comment: You say, 'number of lines above the row containing the column names is not fixed per file'; however, is the structure at the end of that comment block before your csv data rows start consistent?

Comment: Are "comment lines" present after the csv rows start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python version that should work in your Jupyter notebook is below. You'd need to replace `<file_name>`s listed in the line `file_names = ["<file_name1>","<file_name2>"]` with yours.

```py
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

def mine_header(fn):
    '''
    To answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/60249235/8508004

    Takes a file name as input

    Assumes last commented line with contents before the data rows start 
    contains the column names. Could be condensed, to read in all text once and
    then rsplit on last `#` but going line by line at start offers more 
    opportunity for customizing later if not quite matching pattern seen in 
    data files. Also could just assume second last line above the data contains 
    the column names? In that case, could skip 
    `header = [x for x in header if x]` line and use 
    `col_names = header[-2].split(",")` instead.

    Returns list of column names and rest of contents of csv file beyond
    header.
    '''
    # first copy the input file that will be parsed line by to a new file so
    # can parse contents while possibly overwriting the input file with a
    # shorter version if a label for a set encountered inside it
    beyond_header = False
    header = [] # collect the header lines 
    data_rows = "" # collect the data rows
    # go through the file line by line until beyond commented out header
    with open(fn, 'r') as input:
        for line in input:
            if beyond_header:
                data_rows += line
            elif line.startswith("#"):
                header.append(line[1:].strip()) # leave off comment symbol and 
                # remove any leadding and trailing whitespace
            # If line doesn't start with comment symbol, have hit the end of 
            # the header and want to start collecting the csv data tows
            else:
                data_rows += line
                beyond_header = False
    # Now process the header lines to get the column names.
    header = [x for x in header if x]# The last row before the data should be 
    # empty now and so that list comprehension should remove it leaving last row
    # as the one with the column names
    col_names = header[-1].split(",")
    return col_names, data_rows


file_names = ["<file_name1>","<file_name2>"]
df_dict = {}
for i,fn in enumerate(file_names):
    col_names, data_rows = mine_header(fn)
    df_dict[i] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_rows), header=0, names=col_names)

# display the produced dataframes
from IPython.display import display, HTML
for df in df_dict:
    display(df)
```

A pandas dataframe for each is accessible by index matching the list of files you made. For example, the dataframe made from the third csv file would be `df_dict[2]`.

I kind of took it beyond what you asked since splitting the columns to a list was easy to design into the mining function and Pandas is set up to deal with everything thereafter.
If you really wanted to make the output as standard CSV, you could use `col_names` and `data_rows` returned by `col_names, data_rows = mine_header(fn)` and save a CSV file as well. You'd combine them to make a string to save like so:

```py
col_names_as_string = ",".join(col_names)
string_to_save = col_names_as_string + "\n" + data_rows
```